# HTML CSS trying to create an input field which appears over text

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on creating a project in which there are multiple cards created with bootstrap.  Each card has a header, a body, and a footer. When the card is clicked on I want to an input field to appear in the header, footer, and body.  This input field should appear over the current text. 
I have no issue toggling the class, however I am struggling to get my input fields to line up over the text.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
`<div class='card-deck col-3' id='deck'>
        <div class='card grow'>
            <div class='card-header par'>
                <h3 class='target'>${tasks.task}</h3>
                <input id='updateTask' placeholder='Task'>
            </div>
            <div class='card-body par'>    
                <h6 class='target'>Due by: ${newDate}</h6>
                <input id='updateDate' placeholder='Date'>
            </div>
            <div class='card-footer par'>    
                <h6 class='target'> Priority: ${tasks.priority}</h6>
                <input class='update' id='updatePriority' placeholder='Priority'>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>`
```

Here is my JS to toggle the classes:

```
let card = $(this)
card.children('.par').children('.update').toggleClass('hidden');
card.children('.target').toggleClass('remove');
```

Lastly here is the CSS I currently have:

```
.par{
     position: relative;
}

#updateTask, #updateDate, #updatePriority{
    position: relative;   
    z-index: 999;
}

.hidden{
     display: none; 
    z-index:-999;
}
```

I set the class 'par' which houses each set of inputs and text to relative.
Then I set the input fields to absolute.  I have tried many combos of positioning and div restructuring but I have not been able to successfully stack my input field over its respective text.

Unfortunately the JSfiddle does not run because I am using bootstrap in my project.

Answer (score 0):

We gonna use the funcion each, for each element we gonna apply the call "toggleClass".

```
$('#deck input').each(function(index, element){
 $(element).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Just get all .target from #deck and remove it.

```
$('#deck .target').remove();
```

About your class, .hidden display:none will be good but the z-index property cannot be used without the position property. (only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed) https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp )

Comment: This does not solve the issue of positioning the input field and text on top of each other